# Empty array when using _.unique to return distinct value in object

Tags: jquery, lodash

I have an object like this

```
data: [
  {
    "Type":"100, S4",
    "Model":"1 serie, e82",
    "Manufacturer":"BMW",
    "Vehicle":"Cars"
  },
  {
    "Type":"type 2",
    "Model":"a serie",
    "Manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "Vehicle":"Cars"
  },
  {
    "Type":"type 3",
    "Model":"v4",
    "Manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "Vehicle":"SUVs"
  }
]
```

then I used jquery and lodash library with expect to return distinct value from the object.

Tried #1:

```
  $.each( data, function( i, value ) {
    var vehicles = _.uniqBy(value);
    console.log(vehicles);
  });
```

Result: got 3 empty arrays printed in console.log

Tried #2:

```
  $.each( data, function( i, value ) {
    var vehicles = _.uniqBy(value.Vehicle);
    console.log(vehicles);
  });
```

Result: 4 arrays within split characters

```
(4) ["C", "a", "r", "s"]
(4) ["C", "a", "r", "s"]
(4) ["S", "U", "V", "s"]
```

I expected to got an array within

```
["Cars", "SUVs"]
```

How could I deal with it? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to get all `Vehicle` property strings, and then use [`lodash#uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniq) to remove all duplicate strings.

```
var result = _(data).map('Vehicle').uniq().value();
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    "Type":"100, S4",
    "Model":"1 serie, e82",
    "Manufacturer":"BMW",
    "Vehicle":"Cars"
  },
  {
    "Type":"type 2",
    "Model":"a serie",
    "Manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "Vehicle":"Cars"
  },
  {
    "Type":"type 3",
    "Model":"v4",
    "Manufacturer":"Toyota",
    "Vehicle":"SUVs"
  }
];

var result = _(data).map('Vehicle').uniq().value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var vehicles  = _.uniqBy(data, function (e) {
      return e.Vehicle;
    }).map(function(veh){
    return veh.Vehicle;
});   
console.log(vehicles);
```